# Kafka Connect Sink Connector - Single Message Transforms - Filter by value(s)

Tags: filter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, jsonpath

**Context:**
I am writing a custom Kafka JDBC Sink Connector with filter transform (SMT). I want to filter the records by a particular field and value(s).

**Static way (This works) -**

```
{
      "connector.class"                        : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
      ...

      "transforms"                             : "filterUnits",
      "transforms.filterUnits.type"            : "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
      "transforms.filterUnits.filter.condition": "$[?(@.units in [30, 35, 40, 45, 50]",
      "transforms.filterUnits.filter.type"     : "include"
}
```

I want to read filtering values from a file like below:

**Dynamic way (Read from file) -**

```
{
      "connector.class"                        : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
      ...
      "transforms"                             : "filterUnits",
      "transforms.filterUnits.type"            : "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
      "transforms.filterUnits.filter.condition": "$[?(@.units in ${file:/data/app.properties:FILTER_VALUES})]",
      "transforms.filterUnits.filter.type"     : "include"
}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to read filtering values from a **file** or **environment** variable like above ?

**References:**

- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html
- https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators

Comment: The Confluent transform is not open source, but the documentation says nothing about files. You should use Kafka Streams if you really need dynamicness

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your response. I will consider using Kafka Streams.